# ASP.NET: Web Service or WCF for simple ajax call?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-services

I just want to simply call a method on my web service via ajax and have it return a value.

Should I use "WCF Service" , "AJAX-Enabled WCF Service" , or "Web Service"

Which is the easiest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Ajax-Enabled WCF service. I don't remember the name exactly but it should be marked with an attribute to be accessible from JS.

Comment: @John - since @RPM no longer has a comment here, it appears at first glance like you're responding to @Davita, whose answer is the right one BTW.  The Ajax-Enabled WCF service is the way to go - if you're willing to hold your nose and use WCF that is.

Answer (score 4):

Use a generic HTTP handler instead. They are simpler to code.

Comment: Seriously? Please substantiate that surprising statement.

Comment: Why use a web service or wcf service which are effectively built on top of a handler?

Comment: @Phill: why use a high-level language, when it's built on machine code?

Comment: John, To retrieve a simple value from a database you do not need to write an entire service/library. In JQuery you would do something along the lines of $.post(url, data, delegate), where the data is a json object containing parameters to send to the handler. the delegate will execute when the server responds back with the data (or error). None the less @Phil is right, there is no particular need for Ajax Enabled WCF service... its heavy, bloated, and its wasteful (in terms of resources). Besides, if your data access layer spits objects you can always return them as json...

Answer (score 0):

You should never use the "Web Service" template unless you're maintaining existing code and can't change.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just calling a single method use ScriptMethod

You can code it inline with the page that it is used on.
http://www.asp.net/ajax/tutorials/understanding-asp-net-ajax-web-services

> Using the ScriptMethod Attribute
>
> The ScriptService attribute is the
>   only ASP.NET AJAX attribute that has
>   to be defined in a .NET Web Service in
>   order for it to be used by ASP.NET
>   AJAX pages. However, another attribute
>   named ScriptMethod can also be applied
>   directly to Web Methods in a service.
>   ScriptMethod defines three properties
>   including UseHttpGet, ResponseFormat
>   and XmlSerializeString. Changing the
>   values of these properties can be
>   useful in cases where the type of
>   request accepted by a Web Method needs
>   to be changed to GET, when a Web
>   Method needs to return raw XML data in
>   the form of an XmlDocument or
>   XmlElement object or when data
>   returned from a service should always
>   be serialized as XML instead of JSON.
>
> The UseHttpGet property can be used
>   when a Web Method should accept GET
>   requests as opposed to POST requests.
>   Requests are sent using a URL with Web
>   Method input parameters converted to
>   QueryString parameters. The UseHttpGet
>   property defaults to false and should
>   only be set to true when operations
>   are known to be safe and when
>   sensitive data is not passed to a Web
>   Service. Listing 6 shows an example of
>   using the ScriptMethod attribute with
>   the UseHttpGet property.

Comment: Be aware that using `[ScriptMethod]` ties your code to the old ASMX web service technology, which has largely been replaced by WCF. `[ScriptMethod]` can be replaced by WCF, but I might be convinced that it's a good idea where the method will _only_ be called from the page, and where simplicity is more important than generality.

Comment: It may be old (legacy), but it works and is simple and elegant.  There's something to be said for that.

Comment: @mattmc: yes, there's something to be said _for_ it, but quite a lot to be said _against_ it. Consider: how long will it be before new developers look at that code and have no idea what a "[PageMethod]" is?

Answer (score 0):

If those are your only options, I've found the AJAX-Enabled WCF Service to be the simplest to work with.  It's still WCF, but it templates out for you the proper web.config setup and ditches the interface that the plain "WCF Service" template gives you.  It seems to be the closest thing in the whole WCF mess to the old ASMX-style as far as being dirt simple to get going.

Just as another alternative, if you happen to be able to use ASP.NET MVC in your webforms project and just need this for an ajax call, you could skip the web service hoopla altogether and create a simple JSON result for your AJAX call like so:

```
// put this method in a controller
public JsonResult AjaxJsonTest(string who) {
   var result = new {
      Success = true,
      Message="Hello, " + (who ?? "world!")
   }; 
   return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And then you can call it from jQuery like this:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function AjaxTestClick() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '<%: Url.Action("AjaxJsonTest", "Test") %>',
        data: { who: 'whomever' },
        success: function (resultData) {
            if (resultData.Success) {
                alert(resultData.Message);
            }
            else {
                alert('Ajax call failed.');
            }
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Tons of options - pick what suits your situation best.